# Unwanted bounding box around an image

Tags: graphics, eps

I use TeXmaker and I try to insert an image with the command `\includegraphics`.
The problem is that when I compile it, i have a border around my image and I don't want that. I tried everything that I looked up on Google, but still nothing works for me. Can anyone here help me? The problem occurs with `.png` screenshots and `.eps` files that I use. Below you can see what I mean.

[image]

## EDIT:

I compile my text with LuaLaTeX, if that matters.

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{example-image}
\caption{Μετατροπή από την κλίμακα mel στη συχνότητα}
\label{fig:mel2freq}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: `\includegraphics` doesn't add a box, so either it is in the image, or you have `\fbox` or `framed` or similar around the image inclusion, but if you do not show any code it is hard to guess.

Comment: I do not have \fbox or framed, my code is pretty simple:

\begin{figure}
    \centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{mel2freq}
    \caption{Μετατροπή από την κλίμακα mel στη συχνότητα}
\label{fig:mel2freq}
\end{figure}

Comment: @mithri: Then the included image already has the frame.

Comment: try with `example-image` (a test file in the tex distributions, do you still get a frame? if you do please post in your question (not n comments) a complete test document so people can debug

Comment: please make a complete small document using example-image and show the output from that image. if you are getting a frame from that fragment then some code you have not shown is redefining includegraphics or figure, it is impossible to debug the fragment you have posted.

Comment: Make a complete document, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`. You may have something set up in your preamble that adds these boxes.

Comment: Try `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[clip=true,trim=30mm 0mm 0mm 0mm,scale=0.5]{example-image}
\caption{caption text}
\label{fig:mel2freq}
\end{figure}
\end{document}`. I suppose that the whitespace becomes from matlab. - And please read  [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that).